# Trying to dynamically create UI/Image elements and have them updated constantly

Tags: json, list, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build an application for the Microsoft HoloLens in Unity3D. The application will receive data from a python application in the form of JSON. The JSON being sent by python is as follows:

```
{
    "PC_Station": [{
        "PLC_1": {
            "DB1": {
                "test123": 0
            },
            "STOP": false,
            "START": false,
            "Start_1": false,
            "Stop_1": false,
            "Led1": false,
            "Led2": false,
            "Led3": false,
            "Counter": 0,
            "Sliderval": 0
        }
    }]
}
```

The source code for the application is here:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using HoloToolkit.Unity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;
using Windows.Networking;

#endif

public class UDPCommunication : Singleton<UDPCommunication>
{
    // Connection variables
    private string port = "8000";
    private string externalIP = "172.16.24.251";
    private string externalPort = "8001";
    public static int size = 0;
    public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> abc = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    public static List<string> varz;
    public GameObject canvas;
    public GameObject Panel;
    public GameObject image;
    public GameObject imagetext;
    public GameObject numbertext;
    public Image testimg;
    private GameObject getImageTags;
    private GameObject getNumberTags;
    private GameObject[] canvases;
    private GameObject[] panels;
    private GameObject[] tiles;
    private GameObject[] texts;
    private float scaler = 0.0125f;
    // UI/Text elements
    const string TurnOn = "on";
    private uint sliderVal;
    // Sets up a Queue
    private string receivedmsg;
    public readonly static Queue<Action> ExecuteOnMainThread = new Queue<Action>();
    private void Awake()
    {

    }

    IEnumerator updateTags()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.Log("List count" + abc.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < abc.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in abc[i])
                {
                    testimg = GameObject.Find(item.Key).GetComponent<Image>();
                    if(item.Value == "True")
                    {
                        testimg.color = Color.green;
                    }
                    if(item.Value == "False")
                    {
                        testimg.color = Color.red;
                    }
                }       
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        }
    }
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    // Socket initialization
    DatagramSocket socket;
#endif
#if !UNITY_EDITOR


    IEnumerator initGUI()
    {
        while(true){
            if(receivedmsg == null){
                Debug.Log("None");
            }
            else{
                Debug.Log(receivedmsg);
                break;
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
        yield return StartCoroutine(createUserInterface(receivedmsg));
        //yield return StartCoroutine(updateTags());
        Debug.Log("left initgui");
    }
    // use this for initialization
    async void Start()
    {
        /*StartCoroutine(SendSliderValue());
        Button btn_on = led1_button_on.GetComponent<Button>();
        Button btn_off = led1_button_off.GetComponent<Button>();
        Button btn1_on = led3_button_on.GetComponent<Button>();
        Button btn1_off = led3_button_off.GetComponent<Button>();

        btn_on.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Led1 on"); });
        btn_off.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Led1 off"); });
        btn1_on.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Led3 on"); });
        btn1_off.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Led3 off"); });*/
        //string json = "{\"PC_Station\": [{\"PLC_0\": {\"DB1\": {\"test123\": 0}, \"STOP\": false,\"Frap\": false, \"START\": false, \"Start_1\": false, \"Stop_1\": false, \"Led1\": true, \"Led2\": false, \"Led3\": true, \"Counter\": 4002, \"Sliderval\": 0}},{\"PLC_1\": {\"DB1\": {\"test123\": 55}, \"STOP\": false, \"START\": false, \"Start_1\": false, \"Stop_1\": false, \"Led1\": true, \"Led2\": false, \"Led3\": true, \"Counter\": 4002, \"Sliderval\": 0}}]}";

        Debug.Log("Waiting for a connection...");
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.MessageReceived += Socket_MessageReceived;

        //createUserInterface(receivedmsg);
        HostName IP = null;
        try
        {
            var icp = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

            IP = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
            .SingleOrDefault(
                hn =>
                    hn.IPInformation?.NetworkAdapter != null && hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId
                    == icp.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId);

            await socket.BindEndpointAsync(IP, port);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.ToString());
            Debug.Log(SocketError.GetStatus(e.HResult).ToString());
            return;
        }
        SendMessage("test");
        StartCoroutine(updateTags());
        StartCoroutine(initGUI());


    }


    void TaskWithParameters(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log("sending Message");
        SendMessage(message);
    }

    private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        using (var stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(new Windows.Networking.HostName(externalIP), externalPort))
        {
            using (var writer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(stream))
            {
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                writer.WriteBytes(data);
                await writer.StoreAsync();
                Debug.Log("Sent: " + message);
            }
        }
    }
#else


    // Use this for initialization.
    void Start()
    {

    }
#endif
    // Update is called once per frame.
    void Update()
    {
        // Dequeues items until there are no more items on the queue.
        while (ExecuteOnMainThread.Count > 0)
        {
            ExecuteOnMainThread.Dequeue().Invoke();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SendSliderValue()
    {
        Debug.Log("entered slider class");
        GameObject theplayer = GameObject.Find("Hololens-Slider");
        TubeSliderManager test = theplayer.GetComponent<TubeSliderManager>();
        while (true)
        {
            sliderVal = test.CurrentValue;
            string s = "Slidervalue" + sliderVal.ToString();
            SendMessage(s);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
    }


#if !UNITY_EDITOR

    //this method gets called when a message is received
    private async void Socket_MessageReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Read the received message.
        Stream streamIn = args.GetDataStream().AsStreamForRead();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
        receivedmsg = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        //Debug.Log("MESSAGE: " + message);
        // if the count is zero, the message will be relayed to the setStuff method, which processes the string continuously.
        // The message contains a JSON string which is received from the server.
        if (ExecuteOnMainThread.Count == 0)
        {
            ExecuteOnMainThread.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                //Debug.Log(receivedmsg);
                //pass msg to function here
            });
        }
    }
#endif

    IEnumerator createUserInterface(string jsonstring)
    {
        Debug.Log("entered create UI");
        var root = JToken.Parse(jsonstring);
        StartCoroutine(IterateJtoken(root));
        canvases = new GameObject[abc.Count];
        panels = new GameObject[abc.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < abc.Count; i++)
        {
            canvases[i] = Instantiate(canvas, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            canvases[i].name = "Canvas" + i;
            canvases[i].transform.position += new Vector3(i * 14, 0, 30);
            panels[i] = Instantiate(Panel, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            panels[i].name = "Panel";
            panels[i].transform.SetParent(canvases[i].transform, false);
            for (int z = 0; z < abc[i].Count; z++)
            {
                tiles = new GameObject[abc[i].Count];
                texts = new GameObject[abc[i].Count];
                tiles[z] = Instantiate(image, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                tiles[z].name = abc[i].ElementAt(z).Key;
                tiles[z].transform.SetParent(panels[i].transform, false);
                texts[z] = Instantiate(imagetext, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                texts[z].name = abc[i].ElementAt(z).Key + "text";
                texts[z].transform.SetParent(tiles[z].transform, false);
                texts[z].GetComponent<Text>().text = abc[i].ElementAt(z).Key;
                texts[z].transform.position += new Vector3(44 * scaler, -4 * scaler, 0);
                if (Regex.IsMatch(abc[i].ElementAt(z).Value, @"^\d+$"))
                {
                    numbertext = Instantiate(imagetext, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    numbertext.name = abc[i].ElementAt(z).Key + "value";
                    numbertext.transform.SetParent(tiles[z].transform, false);
                    texts[z].transform.position += new Vector3(0, 19.5f * scaler, 0);
                    numbertext.transform.position += new Vector3(77 * scaler, -18.5f * scaler, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        yield return null;
    }



    IEnumerator IterateJtoken(JToken jtoken)
    {
        abc.Clear();
        foreach (var value in jtoken)
        {
            foreach (JArray test in value)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < test.Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (var item in test[i])
                    {
                        var itemproperties = item.Parent;
                        foreach (JToken token in itemproperties)
                        {
                            if (token is JProperty)
                            {
                                var prop = token as JProperty;
                                //Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);           //PLC name
                                var plc = (JObject)prop.Value;
                                Dictionary<string, string> variables = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> val in plc)
                                {
                                    if (val.Value is JObject)
                                    {
                                        JObject nestedobj = (JObject)val.Value;
                                        foreach (JProperty nestedvariables in nestedobj.Properties())
                                        {
                                            size++;
                                            var nestedVariableName = nestedvariables.Name;
                                            var nestedVariableValue = nestedvariables.Value;
                                            variables.Add(nestedVariableName, nestedVariableValue.ToString());
                                            //Console.WriteLine(nestedVariableName+" "+nestedVariableValue);
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        size++;
                                        var variableName = val.Key;
                                        var variableValue = val.Value;
                                        variables.Add(variableName, variableValue.ToString());
                                        //Console.WriteLine(variableName+" "+variableValue);
                                    }

                                }
                                abc.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>(variables));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    }
}
```

The message is received using the function Socket_MessageReceived. As you can see I'm using UDP sockets to receive and send(SendMessage function).
In the async void Start() function I start a Coroutine that sets everything in motion using a function called initGUI().
The Socket_MessageReceived function receives the JSON string I've mentioned above. The received messages will constantly be saved and updated to a private string named receivedmsg.

When I initialize the function initGUI(), the function will wait till the string is not empty, after there's a message received another coroutine will be started. This Coroutine builds the user interface for the HoloLens, the function is called createUserInterface.

In this function the received string will be converted to a JToken and another function called IterateJtoken will be started that adds stuff to a list of dictionaries. After the List of dictionaries is filled, the createUserInterface function builds the interface properly.

While I am able to properly build the userinterface, I want to be able to have the user interface be updated while values in the JSON string change. For instance, in my JSON string I have a variable called "Start", which has a value of false. In the User Interface I have a Unity UI/Image that I change according to the value of the variables. So true means the image will be green and false means the image will be red.

How can i make it so it dynamically gets updated?

I've tried emptying the list of dictionaries each time my Iterate JToken gets called, but that's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems before I even get to your *question*:

1. Your coroutine waiting for the message is broken:

   ```
   IEnumerator initGUI()
   {
       while(true){
           if(receivedmsg == null){
               Debug.Log("None");
           }
           else{
               Debug.Log(receivedmsg);
               break;
           }
       }
   ```

This loop never terminates if `receivedmsg` is empty/null and there are no yield instructions either. You wait for a second *after* the loop terminates instead, which makes no sense. Use [`WaitUntil(() => receivedmsg != null)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html) instead.

You may also want to add an `isEmpty()` check.

2. `createUserInterface` does not need to be a coroutine. You have a single yield instruction inside it and there is no code after it.
3. Same applies to `IterateJtoken`, only this time the yield is for a duration instead of null (why?). I suspect that this might have been intended to be inside one or more of the for loops.

Now, your question. You want to be able to update the GUI, not just build it. My suggestion is to use a dictionary to map between strings (the JSON key) and the Unity GameObject created in `initGui`. Then when you do the update on the new packet data, you query the dictionary instead of creating an object.

Comment: Oh. Right, forgot to change those two back to public void methods, fixed that. I also applied the changes to initGUI like you mentioned. As for your mentioned solution, I will try your suggestion asap.